# Understand the environment configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning NodeJS and Part of it is, I go through the different projects, see how the person implemented/his coding standards and ways and then try to implement it in my custom project

Now, I was going through this repo here (the link is of particular folder) : https://github.com/AnandChowdhary/hovercard/blob/master/config/

Where I saw large chunk of code/files with configuration.

I went through the code inside it and was unable to make any sense out of it.

Usually, In my application i create .env file and then through `dot.env()` Import app configurations

Things like Port address, mongoDb user ID and password, secret keys etc but here the configuration files look totally different

Can someone vaguely explain why are there so many config file in that directory. Second, Since I have only deployed apps using Heroku till date, when people talk about environment as development and production, how do they usually differ?

Would be extremely helpful if you could assist me/share knowledge from your experience.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off that looks like a clientside library being built with webpack, so there's going to be some stuff specific to that environment in there.

For node server-side projects I generally agree that using just environment variables is best; frankly I rarely even use a .env file except as a bootstrap for my Dev environment. 12factor.net is a great resource for explaya lot of best practices in this regard.

As for Dev vs prod, ideally they're as identical as possible, with differences owing only to the development environment having new stuff that you're trying out and testing but aren't ready to release yet.

Differences therefore are usually just things like pointing to a DB full of test data so you're not testing with your customer data, and so on.